Vibration without User Input
I'm struggling to get a vibration working from my App.
I have downloaded Asad/Azam's Morsecode project https://github.com/AsadAzam/MorseCode
and it works, so my device supports vibrations.
App background: I am using on-device speech recognition to identify words and phrases, I want a correct phrase to trigger a small vibration.  In this way, the phone can be in a pocket and a Lavalier Mic can be used to control the app with simple vibration confirmations.
(New Information)
The key to my problem appears to be that I have speech recording (SR) running.  I have just tried the app without SR switched on and the haptics now work as I thought they should.  The question is therefore slightly different: How do I simultaneously have SR and vibrate the phone?  It must be possible as the code below show just this happening when a button is pressed.
Incidentally, I'm using the code for SR suggested by Apple here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/recognizing_speech_in_live_audio
(End of New Info)
My code looks like this:
import SwiftUI
import CoreHaptics
class cInterpreter : ObservableObject
{
    var engine: CHHapticEngine!

    init()
    {
        guard CHHapticEngine.capabilitiesForHardware().supportsHaptics else { return }
        do
        {
            self.engine = try CHHapticEngine()
            try self.engine?.start()
        }
        catch
        {
            print("There was an error creating the engine: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
...
    func someFunc(saidString : String)
    {
        // check if candidate string is recognised
        ...

        // Play a confirmation buzz
        if (foundACandidate)
        {
       //     DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async
       //     {
                let vibe = CHHapticEvent(eventType: .hapticContinuous, parameters: [.init(parameterID: .hapticIntensity, value: 0.81), .init(parameterID: .hapticSharpness, value: 0.8)], relativeTime: 0, duration: 0.12)
                do
                {
                    let pattern = try CHHapticPattern(events: [vibe], parameters: [])
                    let player = try self.engine?.makePlayer(with: pattern)
                    print("Playing...")
                    try player?.start(atTime: 0)
                } 
                catch 
                {
                    print("Failed to play pattern: \(error.localizedDescription).")
                }
       //     }
            
            print("Buzz")
        }

I get "Playing" and "Buzz" in the console, but no haptic on the phone.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?  Cheers.
Extra info:
I tried this in my View:
...
    Button("Press")
    {
AudioServicesPlayAlertSoundWithCompletion(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)) {}
    }
...
    }
    .onChange(of: status.buzz)
    {
        print ("Buzz!")
AudioServicesPlayAlertSoundWithCompletion(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)) {}
    }

The vibe is triggered from the button, but even though the print is generated, there is no vibe from the onChange.
